# LDS Table bound to custom controller

Tags: lightning-design-system

Does anyone have a sample VF page implementing LDS which is bound to a custom controller? I see talk about only being able to access via remote objects and building table using Javascript but nothing about binding to a custom controller. I basically just want to output a 2 column table with the results from my controller

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not a good LDS guy. I was looking to find out the answer. So i end up with the option to create LDS and include those in VF page which bound with controller. I believe this may help you.

This is simple Lightning component

```
<aura:component access="global"  >
    <h1> This is Simple components</h1>
</aura:component>
```

This is the simple application which invokes the component above

> Note:  extends="ltng:outApp" gives you to use LDS in VF pages.

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <c:vfComponent/>
</aura:application>
```

And you can utilize the above application in VF page.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

<apex:includeLightning />
<div id="lightning" />
    <script> 
    $Lightning.use("c:GoodMorningAPP", function() {
     $Lightning.createComponent("c:vfComponent",
          {},
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
          });

    });   
    </script>         
</apex:page>
```